# FPGA large input data

Tags: verilog, fpga

I am trying to send a 4 kilobyte string to an FPGA, what is the easiest way that this can be done?

[This](http://www.terasic.com.tw/cgi-bin/page/archive.pl?Language=English&No=526) is the link for the fpga that I am using. I am using Verilog and Quartus.

Comment: What do you want to do with that string? Store it in FPGA or just process it byte by byte? Is there a specific interface you're using?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question depends a lot on what is feeding this data into the FPGA. Even if there isn't a specific protocol you need to adhere to (SPI, Ethernet, USB, etc.), there is the question of how fast you need to accept the data, and how far the data has to travel. If it's very slow, you can create a simple interface using regular IO pins with a parallel data bus and a clock. If it's much faster, you may need to explore using high speed serial interfaces and the special hard logic available on your chip to handle those speeds. Even if it's slower, but the data needs to travel over some distance, a serial interface may be a good idea to minimize cable costs.

One thing I would add to @gbuzogany 's answer: You probably want to configure that block of memory in the FPGA as a FIFO so you can handle the data input clock running at a different rate than the internal clock of your FPGA.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your FPGA blocks to create a memory inside the FPGA chip (you can do that from Quartus). The creation assistant allows you to initialise this memory with anything you want (e.g: a 4KB string). The problem is that in-FPGA memory uses many of your FPGA blocks, but for a board like this it must not be a problem.

Here is a video explaining how to do that on Quartus:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1nhTDOpY5gU

Answer (score 0):

You can use string for memory initialization. It's easy in Verilog in 'initial begin end' block.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways:
1. You can create a memory block by using Xilinx Core Generator and then load the initial data to the memory, then use the data for the code. Of course, you have to convert the string to the binary data.
2. You can write a code which has a memory to store the string, it can be a First-In-First-Out FIFO memory. Then, you write a testbench to read the string from a text file and write data into the FIFO. Your FPGA can read the string from the FIFO.