# How to store large file to FPGA's DDR3

Tags: memory, fpga, vivado

I need to load the file into an FPGA board. Since the file  (YUV) is around 10MB or more, I believe I would have to store it into the SDRAM (DDR3) then load it into the FPGA. I'm quite new so I am unsure how exactly do I load the file from the PC to the DDR3 through Vivado?  I'm using a Kintex-7 KC705 board. Thank you.

Comment: What interface are you using between PC and the KC705? You can use a DMA engine and transfer data between the Interface peripheral and DDR3 MIG peripheral over an AXI bus.

Comment: @VinayMadapura Thank you for your response. We are using JTAG for this. Can you please elaborate more about the process? We have read the manual but we are still quite confused on how the whole thing works. This is the first time we will be using all of these. Thank you again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FPGA large input data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29620363/fpga-large-input-data)